# C capture ICMP packet

Tags: c, network-programming, system, icmp

I need to test code which deals with ICMP packets, but there is no activity at all. So i thought is there any system function to trigger tsome activity, for instance to make port 80 work you usually do `system("wget 'webaddress'");`. Is there anything similar to that for ICMP? thanks beforehand

Answer (score 1):

The `ping` command would get you close. Modern implementations often default to a random UDP port, but the documentation on your system (e.g. `man ping`) should tell you the option to pass to tell it to use ICMP instead.

Comment: man ping says that ping uses ICMP packets, however when I put `system("ping www.google.com")` nothig is read after this, it's like the program terminates there

Comment: You need to specify what OS you're running on. Some implementations of `ping` run indefinitely, and need an argument to specify how many ping packets to send if you wish to bound it.